# ssh-agent segmentation fault

Tags: openssh, ssh-agent, segmentation-fault

I had openssh running just fine on cygwin. But after a recent update of openssh, I start getting the segmentation fault error when starting ssh-agent. Has anyone encountered such behavior and how can I resolve it? Many thanks.

```
$ ssh-agent
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

$ cat ssh-agent.exe.stackdump
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=00403D0E
eax=00000001 ebx=E577AAB4 ecx=00000000 edx=611551C4 esi=00000A90 edi=612263A4
ebp=0022CD48 esp=0022CC60 program=C:\cygwin\bin\ssh-agent.exe, pid 3508, thread main
cs=001B ds=0023 es=0023 fs=003B gs=0000 ss=0023
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0022CD48  00403D0E  (61227AAA, 00000000, 0022CD88, 61006E73)
0022CD88  61006E73  (00000000, 0022CDC4, 61006720, 7FFDE000)
End of stack trace
```

Comment: Have you tried switching back to the old version of openssh? Or at least switching to a different version?  Might not address your problem directly, but is probably the quickest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching back to the previous version worked for me. I was seeing the same behavior as OP. The version I have now is 5.5p1 (working). The newer version (5.6, I think), is not working.